# How can i source bashrc before ansible ssh

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, ansible

My new ec2 host has default python2.6.
I have script `python_27.sh` which basically update the PATH with python 27 and export some other stuff like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to enable python 2.7

Then i create virtualenv with that python like `/home/ansible/virualenv`

This i am using in hosts like

```
ansible_python_interpreter=/home/ansible/virualenv
```

The error i get is

```
 libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
```

directory

I think that is because when ansible ssh into it it does not source python 2.7 sh file which enables the new library config.

Is there any way ansbile can source that first thing before ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `~/.bashrc` sourcing, you can do the following:

```
ansible_python_interpreter=env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/path/here /home/ansible/virualenv
```

So you will not source `~/.bashrc` (what generaly speaking is not a good idea),
but set only the variable you need.

Comment: If i have 4 env variables which i want to source can i source some script before virtualenv like `source myscript.sh` rather than adding 4 long variables in that line